# Consulta lenta sql server - datos enormes

Tags: sql, sql-server

disculpen una consulta he creado una vista que tiene dos tablas que tengo que hacer join , pero cada tabla tiene un monton de datos.

**la primera tabla llamada: HDESAPP001 tiene 3309935 registros**

**la segunda tabla llamada: HAPEAPP001 tiene 472723 registros**

al hacer esto se demora una eternidad y hace lento la consulta alguien me podria ayudar ?

```
 select f16.HPGCOD, 
        F16.HHCMOD, 
        F16.HHSUCOR, 
        F16.HHTRAN, 
        F16.HHNREL,
        F16.HHFCON,
        F16.HHCTA,
        F16.HHOPER,
        F16.HHMODUL,
        F16.HHTOPER,
        F16.hfecpro, 
        cf.*, 
        f15.HHUSING  
        from storage.[com_act].[HDESAPP001] f16 --select top 1 * from  storage.[com_act].[HFSH016]  
        left join storage.[ref].[RSEGAPP01] cf 
             on f16.HHCMOD = cf.[RCODMOD] 
             and f16.HHTRAN = cf.[RCODTRAN] -- tabla q contiene las transacciones de las agencias (se encuentran los codigos en el word enviado)  
        inner join storage.[com_act].[HAPEAPP001] f15 
             on f15.HPGCOD = f16.HPGCOD 
             and f15.HHCMOD = f16.HHCMOD 
             and f15.hHSUCOR = f16.hHSUCOR 
             and f15.hHTRAN = f16.HHTRAN 
             and f15.HHNREL = f16.HHNREL 
             and f15.HHFCON = f16.HHFCON  
         where f15.hHFCON>= '20210301'  
             and cf.RDCAN in ('AGENCIAS' ,'BN')
```

Comment: La consulta no tiene nada extraño, por lo que seguramente el problema debería pasar por el lado de lo índices y el plan de ejecución. Te sugiero que agregues  la información de lo índices y una salida del plan de ejecución al menos. Saludos.

Comment: El volumen de datos no es tan dramaticamente alto, diría que puedes lograr una ejecución muy rápida. Sin ver el plan de ejecución, es difícil poder decir dónde está el problema y menos como resolverlo.

Comment: Ahí hay 3 tablas. Para poder ayudarte, necesitas publicar el script de creación de las tablas incluyendo índices y constraints. También es necesario el plan de ejecución real de la consulta.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que puedes presentar son los índices y los planes de ejecución, hay que revisar los índices que tienen las tablas involucradas, revisar que no existan índices duplicados entre otras cosas. Te dejo [unos enlaces](https://www.respuestasit.com.mx/2020/06/ejemplos-practicos-de-indices.html) que hablan de ese tema.

Answer (score 0):

A i me paso una vez, es posible mejorar la velocidad de las consultas creando índices. pero no a la loca, los índices serian en los campos donde se realicen consultas específicamente o donde se hagan relaciones (FOREIGN KEY). en el caso de tus tablas serian:

```
--Estructura
CREATE INDEX nombre_del_indice ON nombre_de_la_tabla (campo_de_de_la_tabla);

--Ejemplo con tus tablas
CREATE INDEX idx_HDESAPP001_uno ON storage.[com_act].[HDESAPP001] (HHCMOD)
CREATE INDEX idx_HDESAPP001_dos ON storage.[com_act].[HDESAPP001] (HHTRAN)

CREATE INDEX idx_RSEGAPP01_uno ON storage.[ref].[RSEGAPP01] (RCODMOD)
CREATE INDEX idx_RSEGAPP01_dos ON storage.[ref].[RSEGAPP01] (RCODTRAN)
```

Tambien es conveniente en los campos donde se hagan filtros (WHERE)

```
CREATE INDEX idx_HDESAPP001_tres ON storage.[com_act].[HDESAPP001] (RDCAN)
CREATE INDEX idx_HDESAPP001_cuatro ON storage.[com_act].[HAPEAPP001] (hHFCON)
```

Prueba con estasopciones, y mejorara el tiempo de la consulta